# Writing unit tests for a node service that uses child_process

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, child-process, chai, istanbul

I have a node service where i use child_process to spwan a child, in my case the child is a C++ binary which takes STDIN and streams STDOUT. The service is working as expected and now i'm trying to write unit tests for the methods in service using mocha/chai and running the tests via Istanbul. I have laid out the base for these stuufs, but just want to get an example on how to write unit tests for a node service that uses child_process. Based out of that example i can try to write the unit tests for my service and run them on Instanbul to generate coverage reports.

The service spawns the child like this,

```
var spawn             = require('child_process').spawn,
    child             = spawn(pathToBinary);
child.stdin.write('JSON');
child.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
    //perform operations here
});
```

Comment: Its better to write tests for all the cases that can hit the callback to the data event. Hence, its not the callback you want to test, but the stuff you are eventually going to write inside it...

Comment: @deostroll could you provide some link for an example unit test for this type of STDIN/STDOUT scenarios?

Answer (score 1):

This is a very trivial example, but might be of some help.

```
'use strict';

var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
var expect = require('chai').expect;

describe('test', function() {
  it('should return testing', function(done) {
    var cat = spawn('/bin/cat');

    cat.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
      expect(data.toString()).to.equal('testing');
      done();
    });

    cat.stdin.write('testing');
  });
});
```

Comment: thank you, this example gave me an idea to start with.. in my scenario the stdin would take a JSON with the required key:val pairs for the binary and the stdout is a JSON which is fundamentally a data stream..